# How can I get _i string from local time? (way to get local time with 7 decimal milliseconds)

Tags: momentjs

I need to get local time (from moment variable) with 7 decimal milliseconds but I can't find format like 'ss.SSSSSSS'

if I do

```
     date.local().format('YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.SSSSSSS')
```

it rounds up after 4 decimal like 11.1230000

I know moment has _i variable which shows 7 decimal milliseconds. 
like

```
date.local()._i
```

but I think I am not supposed to access this.

I know I can get UTC time with 7 decimal milliseconds but I can't find a way to get local time with 7 decimal milliseconds. Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Moment.js objects provide a wrapper for the Date object in javascript which is limited to three decimal places.

it looks like you can apply a 'monkey patch' to get your desired result but its likely to be a messy fix. You can see this issue that was created for momentjs here:
https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/3256 which also contains the code to apply the patch.